# Return data from two tables based on identical value

Tags: php, postgresql

I have two tables with 3 columns each

**People**

```
id_number / first_name / last_name / town

T1234     / James      / Smith     / Dant
T1235     / Peter      / Mantle    / Dant
T1236     / Milly      / Wong      / Mormer
T1237     / Susan      / Tan       / Dant
```

**Dates**

```
number / id_reference / expiry

T1234  / Student id   / 24/12/2018
T1235  / Library Card / 23/07/2019
T1236  / Library Card / 16/07/2019
T1235  / Licence      / 02/03/2018
```

I'm trying to run a query to display data from both efficiently but having issues. Basically what I need is to run a query and get an answer like below with data from both tables, id_number and number are the same. So I need the query to find the data from one table, then get the expiry date from another:-

```
id_number / last_name / expiry

T1234     / Smith     / 24/12/2018
T1235     / Mantle    / 23/07/2019
T1237     / Tan       / 02/03/2018

<?php

        $dbconn = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 dbname=sammy_nt user=sammy_nt password=******) or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
    $town = pg_escape_string($_POST['town']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM People p, Dates d
            WHERE p.id_number=d.number
            AND p.town='$town'
            ORDER BY p.id_number";

        $result = pg_query($query); 
        if (!$result) { 
            echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>"; 
            echo pg_last_error(); 
            exit(); 
        } 

        while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $myrow['id_number'], htmlspecialchars($myrow['last_name']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['expiry']));
        } 
        ?>
```

Please assist.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: @Mureinik wrong results, I'm not getting the expiry, just a blank column, the rest works I get the right data, but need the expiry from the other table to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you have 2 tables. `People` and `Dates` from which you want to fetch data. You can use the below SQL Query with `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT People.*, Dates.* FROM People INNER JOIN Dates ON People.id_number = Dates.number"
```

Please note that you can append SQL Query from `WHERE` and with `ORDER BY` and/or `LIMIT` as you would normally do.

Explanation of this is below:

First you have `SELECT`. After that you have `People.*`, which means that All from table People. So you write table name and the `.` and field (`*` for All). Add a comman `,` after this and then the next table with the same syntax. In your case it is `Dates.*`. Then you add `FROM` First Table Name. After this you add `INNER JOIN` and Second Table Name. After this you define the reference between the two tables by `ON` and then the fields from both the tables `People.id_number = Dates.number`. Syntax is the same, `Table.Field`.

Now you can simply display the result normally.

Please note that I have provided you with the SQL Query that you can insert in your code. It might be PDO or Prepared Statement.

If you require further clarification, do not hesitate in letting me know.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works, but doesn't display the expiry, is my display syntax correct?

Comment: To display any field from the fetched results, simply use `$myrow['expiry']`, where `expiry` will be replaced with the field name from your tables. Try with this and check.